# Is Implicit differentiation make same graph as explicit differentiation does?

Tags: functions, implicit-differentiation

Consider a function,

$$y=arcsin(x)$$
When differentiation is done implicitly it gives
$$dy/d x=1/cosy-------(1)$$
And if differentiation is done explicitly it gives
$$dy/dx=1/√(1-x^2)$$
I want to know if they will make same graph in coordinate axes ? I cannot di it myself because i dont know what value i should put in eqn (1) to graph it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that since $y=\arcsin (x)$,  we have $\cos y=cos(\arcsin (x))$ .  To compute the trig function of an arctrig function, we set up a right triangle to take us from the original side ($x$), to the associated angle ($\arcsin (x)$,  then find the $\cos$ of that angle.

So, $\sin$ is $\frac {\text{opposite}} {\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac x 1$,  this makes the adjacent side $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.   Then $$\cos (y)=\cos(\arcsin(x))=\frac {\text{adjacent}} {\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac {\sqrt{1-x^2}}1={\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

So for points on your curve, the two are equivalent